# Highlight cell that doesn't have only letters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to develop my first conditional formatting on VBA, but after hours of trial it still doesn't work.

I'm aiming for a formula that would change the background / highlight the text of a cell that contains something else than any alphabet letters (not sensitive to caps or not). Accents, numbers and special characters would be the trigger

Here is my current code
Thank you in advance for your help

```
Sub Highlight()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Selection
    
MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , Formula1:="=IsAlpha()=false"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

And IsAlpha would be a function like

```
Function IsAlpha(s) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = Len(s) And Not s Like "*[!a-zA-Z ]*"
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put it in the main post 

Function IsAlpha(s) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = Len(s) And Not s Like "*[!a-zA-Z ]*"
End Function

Comment: Are you applying this to multiple cells at a time, or just one cell at a time?

Comment: @BigBen If possible I'd like to apply it on a full column of a data base at a time, but I wanted to make it work for 1 at a time to begin. (maybe not the best idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to `IsAlpha`. Try the following:

```
Sub Highlight()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Selection
    
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
    
    Dim s As String
    s = "=NOT(IsAlpha(" & MyRange.Cells(1).Address(False, False) & "))"
    
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:=s
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed 'Or use RGB...
End Sub
```

In action:
[image]

Comment: For now I don't have any change on the sheet

Currently we are only using the IsAlpha Formula with a Conditional Formating saying if the answer is FALSE, then put the background of the cell in red 

Thank you for the help, It'll be useful to build the macro

Comment: Hmm. What range do you have selected when you run the macro? Is the `IsAlpha` code in a regular code module?

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Not Pure Alpha

- There is a delay of about 2s before the cells get colored (on my machine). I wonder if a worksheet change would handle this smoother (if the range contains values (not formulas)).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightNotPureAlphaTEST()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        HighlightNotPureAlpha Selection
    End If
End Sub

Sub HighlightNotPureAlpha(ByVal rg As Range)
    With rg
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        ' To not highlight blanks...
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , _
            "=NOT(IsAlphaOrBlank(" & .Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "))"
        ' To highlight blanks:
        '.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , _
            "=NOT(IsAlpha(" & .Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "))"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End Sub

Function IsAlphaOrBlank(ByVal S As String) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    IsAlphaOrBlank = Not S Like "*[!A-Za-z]*"
End Function

Function IsAlpha(ByVal S As String) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    If Len(S) > 0 Then IsAlpha = Not S Like "*[!A-Za-z]*"
End Function
```